# Principle equivalent to $\diamondsuit_\kappa$

Tags: set-theory

Let $\kappa>\omega$ be regular. The principle $\diamondsuit_\kappa$ is as follows: There exists a sequence $\langle X_\alpha\mid \alpha<\kappa\rangle$ such that each $X_\alpha\subseteq\alpha$ and for any $A\subseteq\kappa$, the set $\{\alpha<\kappa\mid A\cap\alpha=X_\alpha\}$ is stationary in $\kappa$.

($\diamondsuit^*_\kappa$) For fixed $\gamma<\kappa$, there exists a sequence $\langle Y_\alpha\mid \alpha<\kappa\rangle$ such that each $Y_\alpha\subseteq\alpha\times\gamma$ and for any $A\subseteq\kappa\times\gamma$, the set $\{\alpha<\kappa\mid A\cap(\alpha\times\gamma)=Y_\alpha\}$ is stationary in $\kappa$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [MR0523488 (80c:03050)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=523488)
Devlin, Keith J.
*Variations on ♢*. 
J. Symbolic Logic 44 (1979), no. 1, 51–58.

Comment: In $\diamondsuit_\kappa^*$ do you mean that there is such a sequence for each $\lambda<\kappa$, or that there is at least one $\lambda<\kappa$ for which there is such a sequence?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott For each $\gamma<\kappa$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: That $\diamondsuit_\kappa^*\to\diamondsuit$ is trivial: just take $\lambda=1$. For the other direction let $\langle X_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\rangle$ be a diamond sequence for $\kappa$, fix $\gamma<\kappa$, and fix a bijection $h:\kappa\to\kappa\times\gamma$.

- Show that $C=\{\alpha<\kappa:h[\alpha]=\alpha\times\gamma\}$ is a club in $\kappa$.
- Then for $\alpha<\kappa$ let $$Y_\alpha=\begin{cases}
  h[X_\alpha],&\text{if }\alpha\in C\\
  0,&\text{otherwise}\;,
  \end{cases}$$ and show that $\langle Y_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\rangle$ has the desired property.